# Twitching/shaking after intense exercise? How to lessen it?

Tags: muscle-recovery, energy

So I am emasculated by the roid boys at the gym who can grind through dozens of sets and look like they're just starting their workout after spending days in the sauna. I often have to compensate for this by pushing myself extremely hard, which results in hours of trembling/shaking in said muscle group.

Don't get me wrong: it's not overworking because I'm still seeing results, but it's just unsettling to have to shake like I'm (no offense to him personally) Michael J. Fox. I know the shaking is a result of extreme nervous system taxing (and I extra stimulate my nervous system with lots of caffeine too).

It's also not just in said muscle area, but makes my whole body have spasms/tiny tremors and even mild eye/facial twitches for a while. This happens only after extreme exercising and usually caffeine.

I just want to get through a super-intense workout without having to shake as it greatly affects things like typing; sitting still without looking like I'm having tremors; etc. I just push myself this hard because I know that I'm comparing against IFBB pros without having to use the dope, and that's confidence boosting. I'd be highly proud of myself if I could reach 2/3 the size of those IFBB guys naturally.

I'd be even more ecstatic if I could do it without having to shake excessively after a die-hard workout.

Any tips? How to reduce the shaking/trembling/etc.? Assuming I don't lower-intensity of course.

Answer (score 2):

Shaking or trembling after a workout might be cause for alarm, but in many cases, the problem is due to something simple, such as fatigue or malnourishment. Taking measures before and after working out can help prevent the shaking in many cases, and it is often easily treatable when it occurs. If you shake consistently after your workout or shake when you are not working out, **consult a doctor.**